# Jquery - show/hide on hover events for two elements conflict

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, mouseover, jquery-hover

This question is fairly straight forward but I'm unable to find good relevant example to solve my issue. I have a menu bar that when a user mouseovers an item, a submenu `div` appears.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sx9J2/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#">MENU ITEM</a>
</div>

<div class="box">
    THIS IS THE BOX
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".nav a").hover(
        function(){
            $(".box").show();
        }, function() {
            if (!$(".box").is(":hover")) $(".box").hide();
        }
    );

    $(".box").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

The code above works in many cases but I have seen times in my testing when the `div` would hide even with the mouse over it. My guess is that there must be some sort of conflict between the events. The problem is **particularly bad in Firefox and IE**.

What is a better way to tackle this sort of visual effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a 1px gap between the menu item and your .box element. Set `top: 37px` and it should work

**Edit:**

You have to wrap the submenu and the menu item and listen to the hover event of the wrapper:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sx9J2/7/

Comment: The problem still occurs. It is particularly bad in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The box item is always wider than the menu item and there are several menu items so there cannot be a single wrap for both..

Comment: I've updated the fiddle link. It's still wrapped, but the width doesn't matter, because the wrapper is `display: inline` and the wrapper is wrapped again with the nav bar

Answer (score 1):

You have a very small gap in between your Menu and your box. If you change your top CSS to

```
 .box   {position:absolute; top:36px; background:#eee; width:200px; height:100px;left:18px;display:none}
```

That worked better for me

Comment: The problem still occurs. It is particularly bad in Firefox.